# Loopback + Socket.io limit by user context

Tags: node.js, socket.io, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm creating my app like in example - https://docs.strongloop.com/display/MSG/Building+a+real-time+app+using+socket.io+and+AngularJS

And user client receives **ALL** orders via sockets. How to **limit** publishing orders to current user via sockets? 
For example, user have to get via sockets only orders witch was created by him. Where I have to put condition for publishing in socket, something like

```
where : {
    userId: user_id_from_context
}
```

Comment: I don't think we can help you until you show us the server-side code you are using for receiving and sending order notifications.  That's where the logic has to be implemented to notify only the proper user.  Also, it occurs to me that you're trying to notify the user who just submitted an order - is that really necessary?  That user knows they just submitted an order.  Any info about the order can be returned from the post that submitted it.

Comment: Hello, @jfriend00. Thank you. I've created question with more details – http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38220945/loopback-socket-io-custom-notifications